# Howto make the withdraw stop when the balance below 25$

Tags: java

Here my code.
Main SavingsDemo.java

```
public class SavingsDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create a SavingsAccount object with a $100 balance,
      // 3% interest rate, and a monthly service charge
      // of $2.50.
      SavingsAccount savings =
                   new SavingsAccount(100.0, 0.03, 2.50);

      // Display what we've got.
      System.out.printf("Balance: $%,.2f\n",
                        savings.getBalance());
      System.out.println("Number of deposits: " +
                         savings.getNumDeposits());
      System.out.println("Number of withdrawals: " +
                         savings.getNumWithdrawals());
      System.out.println();

      // Make some deposits.
      savings.deposit(25.00);
      savings.deposit(10.00);
      savings.deposit(35.00);

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.printf("Balance: $%,.2f\n",
                        savings.getBalance());
      System.out.println("Number of deposits: " +
                         savings.getNumDeposits());
      System.out.println("Number of withdrawals: " +
                         savings.getNumWithdrawals());
      System.out.println();

      // Make some withdrawals.
      savings.withdraw(100.00);
      savings.withdraw(50.00);
      savings.withdraw(10.00);
      savings.withdraw(1.00);
      savings.withdraw(1.00);

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.printf("Balance: $%,.2f\n",
                        savings.getBalance());
      System.out.println("Number of deposits: " +
                         savings.getNumDeposits());
      System.out.println("Number of withdrawals: " +
                         savings.getNumWithdrawals());
      System.out.println();

      // Do the monthly processing.
      savings.monthlyProcess();

      // Display what we've done so far.
      System.out.printf("Balance: $%,.2f\n",
                        savings.getBalance());
      System.out.println("Number of deposits: " +
                         savings.getNumDeposits());
      System.out.println("Number of withdrawals: " +
                         savings.getNumWithdrawals());
   }
}
```

Superclass BankAccount.java

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance;              //The balance in the account
    private int numDeposits;             //Number of deposits this month
    private int numWithdrawals;          //Number of withdrawals
    private double interestRate;         //Annual interest rate
    private double monthlyServiceCharge; //Monthly service charge

    /**
    The constructor
    Accept arguments for the balance and annual interest rate.
    @param bal To hold the number of balance.
    @param intRate To hold the number of annual interest rate.
    @param mon To hold the number of monthly service charge.
    */
    public BankAccount(double bal, double intRate, double mon)
    {
        balance = bal;
        interestRate = intRate;
        monthlyServiceCharge = mon;
    }

    /**
    This method to hold the amount of deposit.
    @param amount The amount of deposit.
    */
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount;
        numDeposits++;
    }

    /**
    This method to hold the amount of withdrawal.
    @param amount The amount of withdrawal.
    */
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
        numWithdrawals++;
    }

    /**
    This method to update the balance by calculating the monthly interest
    earned by the account.
    */
    private void calcInterest()
    {
        double monIntRate;
        double monInt;

        monIntRate = (interestRate / 12.0);
        monInt = balance * monIntRate;
        balance = balance + monInt;
    }
    /**
    This method to calculate the monthly service charge.
    */
    public void monthlyProcess()
    {
        balance = balance - monthlyServiceCharge;
        calcInterest();
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        monthlyServiceCharge = 0;
    }

    /**
    This method to hold the number of monthly service charge.
    @param amount The number of monthly service charge.
    */
    public void setMonthlyServiceCharges(double amount)
    {
        monthlyServiceCharge += amount;
    }

    /**
    This method to return the amount of balance.
    @return The amount of balance.
    */
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
    This method to return the number of deposits.
    @return The number of deposits.
    */
    public int getNumDeposits()
    {
        return numDeposits;
    }

    /**
    This method to return the number of withdrawals.
    @return The number of withdrawals.
    */
    public int getNumWithdrawals()
    {
        return numWithdrawals;
    }

    /**
    This method to return the number of annual interest rate.
    @return The number of annual interest rate.
    */
    public double getInterestRate()
    {
        return interestRate;
    }

    /**
    This method to return the amount of monthly service charge.
    @return The amount of monthly service charge.
    */
    public double getMonthlyServiceCharge()
    {
        return monthlyServiceCharge;
    }
}
```

Subclass SavingsAccount.java

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
{
    private boolean status;

    /**
    The constructor
    To accept the argument of balance, interest rate and monthly charge.
    @param bal To hold the amount of balance.
    @param intRate To hold the number of annual interest rate.
    @param mon To hold the amount of monthly service charge.
    */
    public SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate, double mon)
    {
        super(bal, intRate, mon);

        if (bal < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            status = true;
        }
    }

    /**
    This method to determine whether the account is inactive before withdrawals
    is made.
    @param amount The amount of withdrawal.
    */
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (status = true)
        {
            super.withdraw(amount);
        }
    }

    /**
    This method to determine whether the account is inactive before a
    deposit is made.
    @param amount The amount of deposit.
    */
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        if (status = true)
        {
            super.deposit(amount);
        }
    }

    /**
    This method to check the number of withdrawals.
    */
    public void monthlyProcess()
    {
        if (getNumWithdrawals() > 4)
        {
            setMonthlyServiceCharges(getNumWithdrawals() - 4);
        }
        super.monthlyProcess();
        if (getBalance() < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As the question above. I want to make only two withdraw because in the main program when I do 2 withdraw, the balance will become 20$ and it become inactive. But somehow my code did withdraw 5 times. So can someone give me an idea how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: 1) DO NOT USE `double`S or `float`S FOR MONETARY CALCULATIONS! They suffer from severe rounding errors because most decimal fractions don't have a finite binary representation - use [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead. 2) Not all of the code in your question is relevant to your problem. Could you create a [mcve] so that the question becomes easier to read and answer?

Comment: Hi!
In the main class I have 5 withdraws:
// Make some withdrawals.
      savings.withdraw(100.00);
      savings.withdraw(50.00);
      savings.withdraw(10.00);
      savings.withdraw(1.00);
      savings.withdraw(1.00);
I want the program to stop when the second withdraw is called.

Comment: In other words,
I got my out put:
'Balance: $100.00
Number of deposits: 0
Number of withdrawals: 0

Balance: $170.00
Number of deposits: 3
Number of withdrawals: 0

Balance: $8.00
Number of deposits: 3
Number of withdrawals: 5

Balance: $4.51
Number of deposits: 0
Number of withdrawals: 0'
and I want it like:
Balance: $100.00
Number of deposits: 0
Number of withdrawals: 0

Balance: $170.00
Number of deposits: 3
Number of withdrawals: 0

Balance: $20.00
Number of deposits: 3
Number of withdrawals: 2

Balance: $17.54
Number of deposits: 0
Number of withdrawals: 0

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code using the debugger? You find out that you only check the limit once, not every time you touch the `balance`.

Comment: The code run with no bug.

Comment: You're never updating your account `status`; in your `SavingsAccount` class, the only method that updates your account status is `monthlyProcess` which you never call. Before each account activity withdrawl, you'll want to call monthlyProcess(). Also, several `if (status = true)` is reassigning status to *be* `true`, not checking if `status` *is* `true`, you'll want `if (status == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public SavingsAccount(double bal, double intRate, double mon)
    {
        super(bal, intRate, mon);

        if (bal < 25)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            status = true;
        }
    }
```

to

```
public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (getBalance() > 25)
        {
            super.withdraw(amount);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (status = true)
        {
            super.withdraw(amount);
        }
    }
```

to

```
public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (getBalance() > 25)
        {
            super.withdraw(amount);
        }
    }
```